# Удаление строки по нажатию на ячейку

Tags: javascript, dom

Хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, которая находится в ячейке, удалялась вся строка.

```js
var button = document.querySelectorAll('button');

for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  var b = button[i];

  b.onclick = function() {
    var el = this.nodeParent;
    el.nodeParent.removeChild(el);
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}

button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button"></button></td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button"></button></td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button"></button></td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно писать не `nodeParent` а `parentNode`.
Для поиска ближайшего `tr` используем функцию `closest`.
Удаляем через `remove`.

А так у вас код почти правильный, осталось только немного доделать.

Так же в вашем коде перевёл цикл в более красивый и современный вид.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

for (var b of buttons) {

  b.onclick = function() {
    var el = this.closest("tr");
    el.remove();
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}

button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button"></button></td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button"></button></td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>222</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button"></button></td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>333</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Можно ли реализовать этот алгоритм с помощью делегирования? Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @РобертЗайнитдинов что вы имеете ввиду? Кстати вы отметили ответом ответ в котором берутся все кнопки и все tr, и это будет работать неправильно если количество кнопок отлично от количества tr. Если есть какие-то другие кнопки или таблицы. А мой ответ сам находит ближайший tr

Answer (score 1):

```js
var button = document.querySelectorAll('button');
var tr = document.querySelectorAll('tr');

for (let i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    tr[i].remove();
  })
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}

button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button type="button">1</button></td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button type="button">2</button></td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button type="button">3</button></td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```